# Castle Windsor: how to register multiple types as implementing a specific interface?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

**UPDATED**

I have the following classes / interfaces:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    (...)
}

public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
{
    (...)
}

public abstract BaseFoo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    (...)
}

public Bar : BaseFoo<ConcreteType1>
{
    (...)
}

public Baz : BaseFoo<ConcreteType2>
{
    (...)
}
```

Using Castle Windsor, how can I register the types Bar and Baz as implementing IFoo?

I already tried unsuccessfully something like:

```
Register(Types.FromAssembly(typeof (IFoo).Assembly)
        .BasedOn<IFoo>()
        .WithService
        .Select(new List<Type> { typeof(IFoo)})
        .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: the exception stated in the comments tells that the abstract class `BaseFoo` is trying to be resolved. This is because you use `Types` which selects all components, even abstract classes. A simple way to avoid this is to use `Classes` which doesn't have this problem. The [documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Three_steps_14) states:

> Should I use Classes or Types?
>
> There are two ways to start
>   registration by convention. One of them is using Classes static class,
>   like in the example above. Second is using Types static class. They
>   both expose exactly the same methods. The difference between them is,
>   that Types will allow you to register all (or to be precise, if you
>   use default settings, all public ) types from given assembly, that is
>   classes, interfaces, structs, delegates, and enums. Classes on the
>   other hand **pre-filters the types to only consider non-abstract
>   classes**. Most of the time Classes is what you will use, but Types can
>   be very useful in some advanced scenarios, like registration of
>   interface based typed factories.

---

This code looks correct - in fact I tried it in with three different `WithService` calls ([Base](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#_Base__5) [AllInterfaces](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#_AllInterfaces__8) and [Select](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#_Select__10)) and every single one succeeded. I think that it may be the first part of your selection that may not be correct: `Types.FromAssembly(typeof (IFoo).Assembly)`

I didn't find any way to get a list of what castle considers when it tries to use the fluent registration but you can use `Configure` to log the names of the considered components:

```
c.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
    .BasedOn<IFoo>()
    .Configure(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Implementation.Name)) // classes names
    .WithService.Select(new Type[] {typeof(IFoo)})
    .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
```

So try checking whether you're using the right assembly, or if your classes are visible to the container

**EDIT**

This code works:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}
public interface IFoo<T> : IFoo
{
}
public abstract class BaseFoo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
}
public class Bar : BaseFoo<Bar>
{
}
public class Baz : BaseFoo<Baz>
{
}
// main
var c = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
c.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
            .BasedOn<IFoo>()
            .Configure(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Implementation.Name))
            .WithService.Select(new Type[] {typeof(IFoo)})
            .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
var all = c.ResolveAll<IFoo>(); // 2 components found
```

Comment: I think the problem is not so simple, I updated my code sample so it matches my concrete issue.

Comment: I've just updated my test with the structure described and it works just as well (see edited answer). Try adding the `Configure` call I suggested in the classes selection to see what is returned by the filter

Comment: I get this message: {"Requested type [Namespace].IFoo has 0 generic parameter(s), whereas component implementation type [Namespace].BaseFoo`1[T] requires 1.\r\nThis means that Windsor does not have enough information to properly create that component for you.\r\nYou can instruct Windsor which types it should use to close this generic component by supplying an implementation of IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy.\r\nPlease consut the documentation for examples of how to do that."}

Comment: Just one note: the Baz class does not implement BaseFoo<Baz> but BaseFoo<SomeOtherType> 
(same thing for Bar)

Comment: The error message you receive is because you used `Types` instead of `Classes`: `Types` selects all types, including abstract classes. `Classes` doesn't. I thought the error you had was that nohing was being resolved, not that you received this exception; don't hesitate to add it to your question

Comment: what does `WithService.Select(new Type[] {typeof(IFoo)})` do? from question i assume it must populate array with services for IFoo (Bar, Baz), but, i can't catch the mechanics behind it. could you please explain?

Comment: @zloidooraque It is a way to list explicitly the interfaces against which the filtered classes are registered

Comment: @samy yeah, i've understood what it does, but looks like magic to me. like: ok, i know it must return interfaces, but.. thanks anyway (=